# Python doctest string escaping issue

Tags: python, doctest

For this doctest:

```
r'''
>>> uuid_hex_to_binary('8ed2d35f-2911-4c10-ad68-587c96b4686e')
'\x8e\xd2\xd3\x5f\x29\x11\x4c\x10\xad\x68\x58\x7c\x96\xb4\x68\x6e'
'''
```

I'm getting this result:

```
Failed example:
    uuid_hex_to_binary('8ed2d35f-2911-4c10-ad68-587c96b4686e')
Expected:
    '\x8e\xd2\xd3\x5f\x29\x11\x4c\x10\xad\x68\x58\x7c\x96\xb4\x68\x6e'
Got:
    '\x8e\xd2\xd3_)\x11L\x10\xadhX|\x96\xb4hn'
```

The test should pass because the strings are equivalent. However, in the "Got:" string it has converted some of the `\xHH` escapes into their corresponding ascii characters, but it hasn't done this for the "Expected:" string.

If I change `r'''` to `'''` at the begging of the docstring, I get this instead:

```
Failed example:
    uuid_hex_to_binary('8ed2d35f-2911-4c10-ad68-587c96b4686e')
Expected:
    '???_)L?hX|??hn'
Got:
    '\x8e\xd2\xd3_)\x11L\x10\xadhX|\x96\xb4hn'
```

How can I get the two strings to match up in doctest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
>>> '\x8e\xd2\xd3\x5f\x29\x11\x4c\x10\xad\x68\x58\x7c\x96\xb4\x68\x6e'
'\x8e\xd2\xd3_)\x11L\x10\xadhX|\x96\xb4hn'
```

Characters like `'\x5f'` (`'_'`) have printable ASCII values, so in the `repr()` call they get converted to the short form. This isn't what you want, so if you want to compare it with the full version, you will need something like

```
>>> uuid_hex_to_binary('8ed2d35f-2911-4c10-ad68-587c96b4686e') == \
... '\x8e\xd2\xd3\x5f\x29\x11\x4c\x10\xad\x68\x58\x7c\x96\xb4\x68\x6e'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, I figured it out 10 seconds after I asked. I got it working like this:

```
r'''
>>> a = uuid_hex_to_binary('8ed2d35f-2911-4c10-ad68-587c96b4686e')
>>> b = '\x8e\xd2\xd3\x5f\x29\x11\x4c\x10\xad\x68\x58\x7c\x96\xb4\x68\x6e'
>>> a == b
True
'''
```